# cffunction httpMethod attribute validation?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

Is there an administrative option that controls whether the `httpMethod` attribute of an `access='remote'` `cffunction` is validated / required?

I have two server instances, dev and prod, both CF11; on the dev box I can successfully call a remote function defined like:

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="remote" returnFormat="json">
    ...
</cffunction>
```

But on the prod box it returns `500 invalid endpoint definition: no httpMethod declared`.

Easy to fix—just place the attribute on it—but I'd like to bring my setups closer together in terms of configuration.

Comment: Do you know why it is able to function in Dec? What are the differences between the two environments, patch levels, etc?